# How to know which Linux Distribution I'm using?

Tags: linux, version

Moved to https://superuser.com/questions/80251/how-to-know-which-linux-distribution-im-using

How to know which Linux Distribution I'm using?

uname -a gives
Linux xxxxxx.net 2.6.9-42.0.3.EL.wh1smp #1 SMP Fri Aug 14 15:48:17 MDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
How can I know this is Ubuntu/Debian/Fedora or Redhat?

I uses /etc/init.d/serviced restart for restarting serevices, seems it is not Redhat family

Update:

```
[~]$ cat /etc/issue
cat: /etc/issue: No such file or directory
[~]$ cat /etc/issue.net
cat: /etc/issue.net: No such file or directory
[~]$ lsb_release -a
-sh: lsb_release: command not found
[~]$ cat /etc/*-release
cat: /etc/*-release: No such file or directory
[~]$ cat /etc/*-version
cat: /etc/*-version: No such file or directory
[~]$ cat /etc/*release
cat: /etc/*release: No such file or directory
[~]$ cat /etc/*_release
cat: /etc/*_release: No such file or directory
[~]$ cat /etc/*version
cat: /etc/*version: No such file or directory
[~]$
```

Comment: are you connecting by terminal?

Comment: This should be on superuser or serverfault.  It's not a programming question.

Comment: If you are looking for a reliable way to make your program behave accordingly on any given distribution, I'd suggest updating your question before its migrated.

Comment: I don't want to program anything, I just want to get disto info for installing a package.

Comment: underscore, not hyphen, in /etc/redhat_release.  Try /etc/redhat*

Comment: no joy with underscore?  Try rpm -qa | less, and see if there's any clues in the installed packages.

Comment: [itflux][~]$ cat /etc/*release
cat: /etc/*release: No such file or directory
[itflux][~]$ cat /etc/*_release
cat: /etc/*_release: No such file or directory
[itflux][~]$ cat /etc/*version
cat: /etc/*version: No such file or directory
[itflux][~]$

Comment: pm -qa | less
A blank screen and at the end 
-sh: rpm: command not found

Comment: [itflux][~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/bin:/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin://bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin

Comment: Hmm.  Your `PATH` looks okay.  See my answer below.  I think it's Red Hat.

Answer (score 48):

Try this:

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

You could also try /etc/*-version

Comment: [itflux][~]$ cat /etc/*-release
cat: /etc/*-release: No such file or directory
[itflux][~]$ cat /etc/*-version
cat: /etc/*-version: No such file or directory

Comment: `cat /etc/*[_-]release` would be better: some distros use underscore, not hyphen.

Comment: could you please explain how does cat work in this case?

Answer (score 21):

If you have `lsb_release` command,

```
lsb_release -a
```

will tell you (or just use `lsb_release -i`).

`lsb_release` is in [*Linux Standard Base Core Specification*](http://refspecs.freestandards.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/lsbrelease.html).

*Edit*: Looks like you're on a Red Hat system.  A google search on your `uname` output [suggests so](https://www.madmallards.com/stats/).  This is not programmatic, of course!

Comment: $ lsb_release -a

-sh: lsb_release: command not found

Comment: Judging from this and your other answers, looks like you have a really old linux system.

Comment: lsb_relase was created to ease the pain of determining the distro easily from within a program. A lot of systems out in the wild and still in use lack this altogether.

Comment: You're right.  If someone is using that old a distribution, the first step should probably be to upgrade to a more recent version! :-)

Answer (score 11):

/etc/issue or /etc/issue.net give a good clue. Newer distros provide /etc/lsb-release which make it easier to determine exact strings progmatically, i.e. distro name / major & minor release / web site, etc.

In the absence of /etc/lsb-release, its much more difficult, hence the creation of lsb-release.

As Alok said, it looks like you are on a rather ancient (or extremely sparse) system. I don't think this is a case that you can (reliably) progmatically determine with a few lines of code.

If all else fails, check to see what kind of package manager is in use (apt / rpm / others), check to see if /etc/init.d is a symlink (rpm / RH distros) or a directory (debian based distros) .. and you have a pretty good clue as to what you can expect to be present in the root file system as far as structure.

You *can't* please everyone :)

Comment: Debian and derivatives (Ubuntu) also have /etc/lsb-release. They also have the program lsb_release that will give you specific information (you don't have to parse the text file).

Comment: @MichaelM: You're reading a file either way .. either directly opening /etc/lsb-release or scraping the output of lsb_release (either way, you're still reading a file even if its stdout). If doing this progmatically, its best to just parse the file yourself (imho) .. fewer moving parts that may or may not be present :)

Comment: [itflux][~]$ cat /etc/issue
cat: /etc/issue: No such file or directory
[itflux][~]$ cat /etc/issue.net
cat: /etc/issue.net: No such file or directory
[itflux][~]$ lsb_release -a
-sh: lsb_release: command not found

Comment: I uses /etc/init.d/serviced restart for restarting serevices, seems it is not Redhat family
But apt-get and rpm are both giving command not found message

Answer (score 7):

Seems like here's some info:

```
> cat /etc/issue
Welcome to SUSE LINUX Enterprise Server 9 (i586) - Kernel \r (\l).

> uname -a
Linux boxname 2.6.5-7.244-smp #1 SMP Mon Dec 12 18:32:25 UTC 2005 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux

> cat /etc/*-release
SUSE LINUX Enterprise Server 9 (i586)
VERSION = 9
PATCHLEVEL = 3
```

Comment: Whohooo someone does not like the answer, let's hear your opinion ... I've quite often tried to figure out what's running on a box, these are some of the things I look at, it tells you the kernel version, sometimes even the distro name ...

Comment: [itflux][~]$ cat /etc/issue
cat: /etc/issue: No such file or directory
[itflux][~]$ cat /etc/issue.net
cat: /etc/issue.net: No such file or directory
[itflux][~]$ lsb_release -a
-sh: lsb_release: command not found
[itflux][~]$ cat /etc/*-release
cat: /etc/*-release: No such file or directory
[itflux][~]$ cat /etc/*-version
cat: /etc/*-version: No such file or directory
[itflux][~]$

Comment: okay so you have not so standard linux, which is nothing new, but I assume at least `uname -a` give you some response ...

Comment: "Some response" yes; but a useful response?  Not generally.

Answer (score 2):

A list the release filenames for the most common distros:
[Release files](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/release-files.html)

And a function that might help you:
[Shell script](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/user-add-763042/page2.html#post3726139)

Answer (score 1):

EL stands for Enterprise Linux in this case, so I think RedHat or a clone (like CentOS).  I don't know a good way to programatically  find out what distro you're on; there's a few different clues for each one.

```
cat  /etc/redhat_release
cat /etc/debian_version
```

is a good start.  (Note the Ubuntu doesn't modify `/etc/debian_version` when they pull changes from Debian, so my Ubuntu Karmic system has squeeze/sid in debian_version.)

Edit: forgot about lsb.  Good call, Tim Post and Alok.  The whole point of LSB is to give distro-independent ways to do things.

Comment: [itflux][~]$ cat /etc/redhat_release
cat: /etc/redhat_release: No such file or directory
[itflux][~]$ cat /etc/debian_version
cat: /etc/debian_version: No such file

Comment: EL could also be SuSE's Enterprise Linux, aka sles.  It uses RPM like RedHat.  Don't remember how to check for it.

Comment: Oh yeah, Suse has some commands on top of rpm.  If you have yast2 or yum, you're on SuSE.  Look in /etc/ for *suse* or *novell*.

Comment: There is no suse or novell folders under /etc
[itflux][~]$ yum
-sh: yum: command not found

Comment: I googled for your kernel version, and came up with surprisingly few results.  http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/3331503/com/kernel-2.6.9-42.0.3.EL.i586.rpm.html does indicate that it's RHEL or CentOS.  (CentOS = RHEL without the support contract.  Same versions of everything.  Not sure if they manage to make all their binaries identical, but they try.)

Comment: It should be `/etc/redhat-release` and `/etc/debian-version` (hyphens, not underscores)

Comment: @Cocowalla: Ubuntu definitely still uses `/etc/debian_version`.  If there are other Debian-derived distros that use `-` instead of `_`, maybe we need `/etc/debian?version`