# Installing package 'CamelParser' on IDE

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, google-colaboratory, arabic

Package "[Camel Parser](https://github.com/CAMeL-Lab/camel_parser)" was installed and worked fine on Google Colab (python ver == 3.10.12).

However, I wasn't able to install it successfully on two IDEs: PyCharm and Visual Studio Code.

The error messages I got on PyCharm using 2 Python interpreters:

```
- Python 3.11.2
    ○ Error when installing dependencies:
    § ERROR: Ignored the following yanked versions: 0.2.dev0, 0.3.dev0, 0.4.dev0, 0.4.dev1, 0.4.dev2, 0.4.dev3, 0.4.dev4, 0.4.dev5, 1.0.0 
    § ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.3.0 Requires-Python >=3.7.0, <3.10.*; 1.3.1 Requires-Python >=3.7.0, <3.10.*; 1.4.0 Requires-Python >=3.7.0, <3.10.*; 1.4.1 Requires-Python >=3.7.0, <3.10.*; 1.5.0 Requires-Python >=3.7.0, <3.11; 1.5.1 Requires-Python >=3.7.0, <3.11; 1.5.2 Requires-Python >=3.7.0, <3.11 
    § ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement camel-tools==1.5.2 (from versions: 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.2.0) §ERROR: No matching distribution found for camel-tools==1.5.2  

- Python 3.10
    ○ Error when installing dependencies:
        § note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.  § ERROR: Failed building wheel for camel-kenlm Failed to build camel-kenlm § ERROR: Could not build wheels for camel-kenlm, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

The error messages I got on VS code using 3 Python interpreters:

```
- Python 3.11.2
    ○ Error when installing dependencies:
        § ERROR: Ignored the following yanked versions: 0.2.dev0, 0.3.dev0, 0.4.dev0, 0.4.dev1, 0.4.dev2, 0.4.dev3, 0.4.dev4, 0.4.dev5, 1.0.0 
        § ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.3.0 Requires-Python >=3.7.0, <3.10.*; 1.3.1 Requires-Python >=3.7.0, <3.10.*; 1.4.0 Requires-Python >=3.7.0, <3.10.*; 1.4.1 Requires-Python >=3.7.0, <3.10.*; 1.5.0 Requires-Python >=3.7.0, <3.11; 1.5.1 Requires-Python >=3.7.0, <3.11; 1.5.2 Requires-Python >=3.7.0, <3.11 
        § ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement camel-tools==1.5.2 (from versions: 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.2.0)
        §  ERROR: No matching distribution found for camel-tools==1.5.2
- Python 3.10.9
    ○ Error when installing dependencies:
        § ERROR: Failed building wheel for camel-kenlm Failed to build camel-kenlm 
        § ERROR: Could not build wheels for camel-kenlm, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
- Python 3.9.18
    ○ Error when installing dependencies:
        § note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. 
        § ERROR: Failed building wheel for camel-kenlm Failed to build camel-kenlm 
        § ERROR: Could not build wheels for camel-kenlm, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

**Attempts to solve the problem:**

1. I used older Python versions (due to the error message I received while using Python ver 3.11).
2. I used the command "pip install camel-tools==1.5.2" on Python ver 3.11 to force install this module.
3. I installed packages "[camel_tools](https://github.com/CAMeL-Lab/camel_tools)" and "[kenlm](https://github.com/CAMeL-Lab/camel-kenlm)" from the source code.

Your help would be much appreciated! I would be so grateful for your suggestions.

---

*Update:*

The library worked well on Google Colab which runs on [Linux Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75037722/17746590), but not on my Windows 11. To see whether this issue is OS-based, I tried to install the library on Ubuntu (python 3.11.6 and python 3.9.0) as well as on macOS (python 3.9). The same errors persisted.